# Python Multiprocessing: Topping off multiprocessing queue before becoming empty

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make a multiprocessing Queue in Python 2.7 that fills up to it's maxsize with processes, and then while there are more processes to be done that haven't yet been put into the Queue, will refill the Queue when any of the current procs finish. I'm trying to maximize performance so size of the Queue is numCores on the PC so each core is always doing work (ideally CPU will be at 100% use the whole time). I'm also trying to avoid context switching which is why I only want this many in the Queue at any time.

Example would be, say there are 50 tasks to be done, the CPU has 4 cores, so the Queue will be maxsize 4. We start by filling Queue with 4 processes, and immediately upon any of those 4 finishing (at which time there will be 3 in the Queue), a new proc is generated and sent to the queue. It continues doing this until all 50 tasks have been generated and completed.

This task is proving to be difficult since I'm new to multiprocessing, and also it seems the join() function will not work for me since that forces a blocking statement until ALL of the procs in the Queue have completed, which is NOT what I want.

Here is my code right now:

```
def queuePut(q, thread):
    q.put(thread)


def launchThreads(threadList, performanceTestList, resultsPath, cofluentExeName):
    numThreads = len(threadList)
    threadsLeft = numThreads
    print "numThreads: " + str(numThreads)
    cpuCount = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    q = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=cpuCount) 
        count = 0
    while count != numThreads:
        while not q.full():
            thread = threadList[numThreads - threadsLeft]
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=queuePut, args=(q,thread))
            print "Starting thread " + str(numThreads - threadsLeft)
            p.start()
            threadsLeft-=1
            count +=1
        if(threadsLeft == 0):
            threadsLeft+=1
            break
```

Here is where it gets called in code:

```
for i in testNames:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,args=(i,paths[0],cofluentExeName,))
            jobs.append(p)

launchThreads(jobs, testNames, testDirectory, cofluentExeName)
```

The procs seem to get created and put into the queue, for an example where there are 12 tasks and 40 cores, the output is as follows, proceeded by the error below:

```
numThreads: 12
Starting thread 0
Starting thread 1
Starting thread 2
Starting thread 3
Starting thread 4
Starting thread 5
Starting thread 6
Starting thread 7
Starting thread 8
Starting thread 9
Starting thread 10
Starting thread 11

  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 262, in _feed
    send(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 290, in __reduce__
    'Pickling an AuthenticationString object is '
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security re
asons
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 262, in _feed
    send(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 290, in __reduce__
    'Pickling an AuthenticationString object is '
TTypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security r
easons
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 262, in _feed
    send(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 290, in __reduce__
    'Pickling an AuthenticationString object is '
TTypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security r
easons
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 262, in _feed
    send(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 290, in __reduce__
    'Pickling an AuthenticationString object is '
TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security re
asons
```

Comment: That's a really weird way to use a synchronized queue. Usually, you put *jobs* in the queue, not *workers*, and the workers use the queue to get work.

Comment: I didn't write the code, I believe that the threadList is really the jobList. I will ask the code's creator to check.

Comment: `q.put()` already does most of what you want all by itself:  so long as the queue is full (at its defined maximum size), `.put()` blocks.  When something is removed from the queue, `.put()` wakes up and adds the next item.  Unrelated, the error messages you showed must be due to something you _didn't_ show us.  It's always best to give complete example:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey Tim, ok I'll try reducing my code since that sounds simpler to keep trying to put and let the program block itself. As for the error messages, I'm pretty sure they are related to the code... I haven't changed anything else.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the msgs are "related".  But they're not _caused_ by anything you've shown us.  If we can't _run_ the code you post, all anyone can do is make blind guesses.   I've used this stuff a lot, and have never seen an `AuthenticationString` complaint in my life - the code is doing something else, somewhere else that's the true cause of that.  The code you showed is merely triggering it.

Comment: Ahh... well unfortunately this is part of a much deeper project, I was hoping the issue might be something people run into and would have an obvious fix. I can't really provide all the code. On a side, it looks like the threadList is a list of Processes made in another section of code. Will add in above. Might help shed some light.

Comment: Could there be a problem with trying to put a process into the Queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a multiprocessing Pool to accomplish this?

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(your_function, dataset) ##dataset is a list; could be other iterable object
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The `multiprocessing.Pool()` can have the argument `processes=#` where you specify the # of jobs you want to start. If you don't specify this parameter, it will start as many jobs as you have cores (so if you have 4 cores, 4 jobs). When one job finishes it'll automatically start the next one; you don't have to manage that.

Multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: You're a lifesaver. I'll do that instead.

Comment: Happy to help! let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: Ok so I do have a question. In my case, I have threadList which is a list of processes already created. Should work as an iterable object right? So I just pass that in as the iterable, and then I have a function runProc that simply starts the threads in that list as it iterates through them. I'll post updated code above. However, when I do that, still getting a pickle error. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: What is the goal of the script? What function are you trying to start multiple instances of, and what are the parameters for that function (not launchThreads)?

Comment: Each of the processes in threadList is an instance of an exe that is getting run externally with different parameters. Those jobs are created above 'for i in testNames' code segment. The exe is another program entirely, one that is beyond my control. So all those parameters should already be passed into each job in the threadList. The script should be running all these instances into the Pool with all the cpus and then run new instances as the old ones get finished.

Comment: ok; are you using subprocess to start the exe with your parameters?

Comment: So, the prior method that was being used was batching without multiprocessing queues. The code seemed to just call a multiprocessing.Process(target_worker, args=(params, paths, Exe_name), then store these processes into a list, and then call the start() function on them. There was a little more to it, to get them into batches, breaking up the list into smaller lists, but that's essentially what it did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119051/discussion-between-alex-elkman-and-crld).